# Differences in speed using document.getElementById(id), $(id), and containerElement.find(id)

Tags: javascript, html, dom-traversal, dom

Say I have a container element/div on a page. There are other elements outside of it, comprising page layout/navingation, and there is a fair amount of content inside of it.

In my javascript, I need to find/manipulate a few elements inside of that container. If all of these elements have id properties set, speed wise, is it better to use `document.getElementById()` (considering that once found, the element will need to be turned into a jQuery object for manipulation) to find them, or to select them using jQuery like so: `$("#id")`, or to select the container first, store it in a variable, and then select the elements to be manipulated using jQuery like so: `container.find("#id")`?

Which approach is faster? What does the speed of searches like these depend on?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Don't optimize prematurely. Do whatever seems easiest and most clear. Probably, $(...) is. Then, only if it is too slow, try other options and see if it makes it fast enough. Remember that it doesn't need to be as fast as possible--only fast enough.

Comment: jQuery uses `getElementById` under the hood when using `$('#id')`.

Answer (score 1):

As `jQuery()` with an id selector uses `document.getElementById` inside, using the native method directly is obviously faster. Of course the overhead is neglibible (you never need to select hundreds of elements by id), and they do different things - most likely you want to get a jQuery wrapper object containing the DOM node.

`container.find(idselector)` is an interesting case, though. As ids are unique all over the document, you should not need such an expression at all. Because of that, id selections are usually boosted by a `O(1)` lookup table inside the browser, and very fast even for full documents. I'm not sure what happens when you use it inside a container, but it might fall back to a rather slow DOM tree traversal.

Comment: `container.find(idselector)` does indeed fall back to a slower DOM tree traversal: `querySelectorAll`. Unless you are using a browser that doesn't support `querySelectorAll`. Then it falls back to a much slower method!

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for the confirmation, I didn't want to look up this in the Sizzle source :-) Though, there still might be internal optimisations for id selectors which make tree traversal superfluous